# How to get visited websites history (Android)?

Tags: android, web

I want to develop an Android app which can get all **visited websites**

Does any one know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every browser does save a history for itself. so you would need an implementation for every browsers (if that is possible). and i hope most browsers encrypt the history files to make them unreadable. i wouldn't like to have an app look at my browsing history unless i explicitly permit it. but there is not android permission for that, so that wouldnt be possible. maybe there is a way to access the history files of the browsers, but that would probably need root, and i still think you shouldnt do that.

Comment: is there any other way or idea to got the history !?

Comment: no, the histories of the browsers are in their respective /data/ folder on the file system. to access them from another app you need root permission. even if you have that. the files might still be encrypted. and there is no "global" history. so every browser has its own file and format